# Cant see the design layout in android studio

Tags: android, layout

I just updated my android studio to the 1.4 beta 3 version and I have a problem now. I cant see the design of the layouts, the xml it is okay and in runtime there is no problem. Anybody knows what is happening?

[image]

Comment: Don't run beta versions... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can delete **tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"** attribute in content_main.xml file to see the designer tool.

Answer (score 0):

Download a version of Android Studio from the Release channel.  Beta isn't fully tested yet.

** check out this page for most current release version.

https://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/studio.html

Answer (score 0):

Could be that some of your elements lack some basic attributes like "android:layout_width" and Android Studio doesn't show the error for some reason. It was my case.